# If a user says lacking reputations and hence posting comments as answers, but the answer has positive score, is it necessary to flag it?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

Sometimes I find some users says no enough reputation but want to comment, so just post comment as answers. But sometimes their 'answer' can have positive score like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34501073).

Sometimes it looks like the answer even the intent is just posting comments as answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34477096).

And sometimes it is an accepted answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34066957).

My question is, is it worth to flag if a user says posting comments as answer but the 'answer' is getting well received?

Comment: Score does not correlate well with topicality in the case of questions, or the extent to which an answer is a self-contained answer to the question. So yes, flagging, voting to close, voting to delete, and so on are all often appropriate actions even for quite highly-scored posts; at most, a very high score might warrant a stay of execution with a historical lock, rather than being deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No amount of votes will change the fact that a comment-as-answer is not an answer.

However, keep in mind that new users (and new flaggers) tend to have a different definition of "comment". For example, many (including experienced users) consider guesswork or uncertain answers to be comments, in part because comments are seen by the community at large as second-class citizens (which is why even some experienced users have a tendency to answer in comments if they don't feel like fleshing them out for whatever reason). But so long as something provides a direct answer to the question and/or a potential solution to the problem, correctness aside, it's an answer to the question.

In those cases, you can simply suggest an edit removing the part where it says "This should really be a comment", because they all seem to provide some semblance of a solution to the problem (at least, to my untrained eyes), and thus, a potential answer to the question.

Besides, if a user is capable of posting comments-as-answers that are well-received, then there's a reasonable chance they are just as capable of posting actual answers that go on to be well-received.

Comment: Basically it has to actually qualify for a Not an Answer flag, and not just contain the words "I don't have enough rep to comment, but..." or some variation thereof